# Equality of $2$ infinite series

Tags: power-series

If $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kt^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_kt^k \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}  \implies (a_k=b_k  \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N_{0}} )   $$
Prove or make counterexample.I think it's true but don't know how to proceed.

I start $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kt^k =\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{m}b_kt^k  $$
I can only get that $a_0 = b_0$ by setting $t=0$.But then i tried same trick to do for $a_1 = b_1 $ but that didn't help me. 
Maybe it is something trivial but I can't see it.

Comment: technically those aren't polynomials but power series

Comment: maybe its better to $\forall t \in B$ where $B$ is set where both converges

Comment: Indeed, if one or both series have radius of convergence $0$, then we can only conclude $a_0=b_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is equivalent to

$$\forall t:d(t):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty d_kt^k=0\implies \forall k:d_k=0.$$

Clearly, $d(0)=0\implies d_0=0$.

Then as $d(t)$ converges, so does $e(t):=\dfrac{d(t)}t=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_kt^{k-1}$, and $\lim_{t\to0}e(t)=0=d_1$. You can iterate.

Answer (score 2):

This is a property of power series if it is assumed that the series converge in $(-r,r)$ for  some $r>0$. The coefficients of a convergent power series $\sum a_n t^{n}$ are simply $\frac {f^{(n)} (0)} {n!}$ where $f$ is the sum of the series.

Reference: Any book on Complex Analysis starts with this this theorem. But you can simply replace complex numbers by real numbers in the proof and it works fine for real series also.

Comment: Can you provide me reference of proof of that property for power series?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_kt^k$, $g(t) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty b_kt^k$. By hypothesis, $f(t) = g(t)$ $ \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$ f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = a_1$$
and
$$ g'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h) - f(0)}{h} = b_1.$$
Hence $a_1 = b_1$. By continuing this way, you prove equality $a_k = b_k$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Notice that you don't actually need equality of the two series for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, but only for every $t$ in a fixed neighborhood of zero.

Comment: You're using stuff about limits and convergence without stating it, and I'd argue that's the hard part of the problem.